# PHP - how would i be able to save each value of this var dump array?

Tags: php

the site: http://shawn.sc2broadcast.net/test/

the code:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.macsiam.com/sites.php');
preg_match_all('%\'http://([^./]+).[^.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\'%i', $homepage, $domains, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
// $domains[0] is an array of matched full URLs (http://whatever.wherever.com/page.php)
// $domains[1] is an array of matched subdomains (whatever)

var_dump($domains[1]);
?>
```

question: i was wondering how i could save each value of this array seperatly?

Comment: so you want to save the string generated?

Comment: Could you clarify your question by providing example input and desired output?

Comment: Save which values, in what structure, in what capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    foreach ( $domains as $domain ) {
         //balah balah
    }
```